# What does Aquaman steal from the Batcave?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, justice-league, justice-league-2017

In *Justice League (2017)* there's a scene in the Batcave in which Aquaman stole something.

What did he steal?

Comment: (-1) if it was not for the answer, I would not have known what you were talking about. Please provide a picture or a YouTube video of the scene for other users who may or may have not seen *Justice League*, yet cannot remember that scene.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can see it here. It appears to be a black (*what else?*) [Leatherman multitool](https://www.leatherman.com/wave-10.html?dwvar_10_color=11&cgid=multi-tools#prefn1=color&prefv1=Black&start=1)

[image]

Comment: It has a knife 

Comment: @CreationEdge - In fact it has several

Comment: Technically, this is wrong. There's no proof this is a leather man, there's no logo on it. I'm sure it's a Wayne Enterprise multi-tool! Also, for reference, it looks more like the [Super Tool 300](https://www.leatherman.com/super-tool-300-2.html?dwvar_2_color=10&cgid=multi-tools) than the Surge.

Answer (score 6):

Since the film's not accessible to me at the moment, I have only my memory to offer you, but he stole a tool similar to a [Leatherman Super Tool 300](https://www.leatherman.com/super-tool-300-2.html?dwvar_2_color=10&cgid=multi-tools), based on photos and video available since the movie released officially on Digital format. It was taken from the table with assorted gear on it. He hefted it for a moment (evaluating its quality, I assume), and then kept it.

Answer (score 1):

Its a pair of pliers, or a leatherman to be specific. I never see him use them again though.

Comment: Hey, welcome to SFF! How do you know this? Can you please cite your source? Good answers on this site are generally more than just speculation and include their sources.

Comment: This is clearly an answer to the question. Wrong answers are not delete worthy.

Comment: @Edlothiad totally agree! but it would be great if there were some sources/ citations.

Comment: @Shreedhar Sure, that was more for the people in the LQP queue.